# Can AES128 CBC uses 0-padding?

Tags: encryption, aes, padding

Due to some limitation of a client, they are padding the plain text with `0x00` before passing it to the AES alogirhtm, instead of the normal PKCS5/PKCS7 or similar padding.

While it is doable in my server side, I have a question of whether using 0-padding works. Take an example that the plain text ends with exactly the 0-padding character. It is impossible for the server side to distinguish it.

Is 0-padding one of the acceptable padding method and if so how should my side handle the padding correctly?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unsure what is meant by "ASCII code 0", I will assume a byte with the value 0x00? (Yes hex is still a thing) See [Zero padding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Padding_(cryptography)#Zero_padding): *Zero padding may not be reversible if the original file ends with one or more zero bytes, making it impossible to distinguish between plaintext data bytes and padding bytes.*

Null padding (0x00) can work for data that does not end with a null, ASCII text is an example that works. The deprecated PHP mcrypt does this and the null padding creates interoperability issues.

So: yes null padding does work for some data such as text but fails for binary data. It is best not to use it, PKCS#7.PKCS#5 padding is a better and more generally used padding.